# Can you have Amazon Alexa understand email addresses or phone numbers?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to have Alexa understand email addresses or phone numbers? For example, I'd like to tell Alexa to send me an SMS message (and then provide the mobile #), or have her (okay, it) send an email to my account. My guess is that the tech isn't there yet, but...?

Comment: I should add, I am building a custom skill as a developer. Might add some context :).

Answer (score 1):

They have some built-in slot types to handle common info types, such as time or postal code:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#slot-types

But they don't have e-mail or phone number and the LITERAL, which you could have used to get an e-mail address is now deprecated.  They do have AMAZON.NUMBER which you could use to get the phone number, but I think it would be a poor user experience.

You might want to wait until they add more built-in slot types or provide a way for the skill to request that Amazon give it some user information.

Comment: Thanks for your note!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `AMAZON.NUMBER` slot type for this.

When you test it in the simulator you have to make sure to write the actual numbers though, for instance:

"my phone number is seven seven three, five five five, five five five five".